# SQL Server concatenation varchar and int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two variables:

One is varchar and one is int, I am not sure how to write a while loop using casting so that it will show the following: for example if the while loop is 5 then the result should be 
Meter 1
Meter 2
Meter 3
Meter 4
Meter 5.

I have this code, but it is not running (cannot convert varchar to int) even when i do the casting it does not work.

```
DECLARE @Name varchar (20) = 'Meter',
        @MeterNumber int = 1

WHILE (@MeterNumber < 5)
BEGIN
PRINT @Name + ' ' + @MeterNumber
SET  @MeterNumber = @MeterNumber + 1
END
```

Comment: you need to cast or convert @MeterNumber to a varchar, when you print it out

Answer (score 15):

This should do the trick: cast the MeterNumber to a varchar when you print it.

```
DECLARE @Name varchar (20) = 'Meter',
        @MeterNumber int = 1

WHILE (@MeterNumber <= 5)
BEGIN
PRINT @Name + ' ' + cast(@MeterNumber as varchar(20))
SET  @MeterNumber = @MeterNumber + 1
END
```

**EDIT:**

> For example I want to declare a third variable that would store each
>   iteration. Meter 1, Meter 2... but I am not sure where to place it!

```
DECLARE @Name varchar (20) = 'Meter',
        @MeterNumber int = 1 ,
        @OutPut varchar(max) =''; -- this can get biiiig.

WHILE (@MeterNumber <= 5)
BEGIN
SET @Output = @Output + @Name + ' ' + cast(@MeterNumber as varchar(20)) + ','
PRINT LEFT(@Output, len(@Output) - 1)
SET  @MeterNumber = @MeterNumber + 1
END
```

Comment: how if I want to store the result in a variable each time?

Comment: which result do you mean? The print?

Comment: For example I want to declare a third variable that would store each iteration. Meter 1, Meter 2... but I am not sure where to place it!

Comment: @ShathaS Ok. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GoatCO sure, thank you. All your tweaks make sense, except that you should remove the last ',' before you print it out. :)

Comment: @OutPut varchar(max) = ''; --otherwise this variable will not be set

Comment: @FabianBigler you can do this to get rid of the last comma--    PRINT left(@Output, len(@Output) - 1)

Comment: @ArghyaC I know but I was too lazy. ;] Changed it to make you happy, though.

Comment: @ArghyaC Thank you. You would earn +1 too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one (without `LOOP`) -

```
DECLARE
      @Name VARCHAR(20) = 'Meter'
    , @MeterNumber INT = 5
    , @OutPut VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @OutPut = STUFF((
     SELECT CHAR(13) + @Name + ' ' + CAST(sv.number AS VARCHAR(5)) 
     FROM [master].dbo.spt_values sv
     WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
     AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND @MeterNumber
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @OutPut
```